# cannot allocate memory to kill the memory hogger

Tags: linux, operating-systems

I have a remote Linux server (Amazon lightsail) and installed some service on it that's hogging all memory. I can barely SSH onto it, and when I run sudo killall java (it runs java), I get a bash error saying it can't allocate memory.

How can I bypass that and kill the offending service ?

Answer (score 1):

Is there swap in place? If it isn't, I'd advice to add some to avoid such a situation in the future. You may also try to kill processes one by one, instead of killall.

Eventually you may try just ssh in non-interactive mode. It should require less memory:

```
ssh root@yourserver 'kill -9 {pid}'
```